# density line cuts negative values using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphic

I'm drawing a weighted density function using ggplot2. I've data from various years (2008 to 2017), and I draw the density function for each year. But in 2 years negative values are cut:

(image)density function with cut negative values
[image: (image)density function with cut negative values]

```
ggplot(subset(ECV_CAT0817,HB010==2017)) + 
  geom_density(aes(rendaOCDE, weight=DB090/sum(DB090))) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-5000,50000))
```

The rest of the years negative values appears correctly, for example:

(image)density function with negative values correctly
[image: (image)density function with negative values correctly]

How can I avoid the cut in negative values using ggplot2?

If I use plot and density functions, the values appears correctly, but I want to use ggplot2.

(image)using plot function
[image: (image)using plot function]

```
plot(
  density(
    subset(ECV_CAT0817, HB010==2017)$rendaOCDE, 
    weights=subset(ECV_CAT0817, HB010==2017)$DB090/sum(subset(ECV_CAT0817, HB010==2017)$DB090)),
  xlim=c(-5000,50000))
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: A sample of your data is required. Use dput(data)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Dput function creates a file with size 177 MB, very large. I can upload the .RData file containing the dataframe. Thanks.